# Matlab, Extracting Particular Values from an Excel File

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, average, data-analysis

If I have a table of values in Matlab ( here I have a 40k rows, and about a dozen columns), how can I read only particular values from each row? My goal is to extract some of the values from each row, and average them.

For context, each row of data is a measurement taken at a particular minute, and each measurement is a temperature value. I have the temperature readings of several individuals in side by side columns in the excel file, and my goal is to create an actigram showing an 'average' individuals temperature oscillations over time.

Thank you!